# Jquery ajax call in Cake PHP 3.0

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

---

Hi,
I'm trying to make a ajax request to the view A from the controller B like this :

In the view A :

```
var tab = new Array();
    function updateResult(){
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'B','action'=>'viewresult'));?>",
                dataType: 'text',
                async:false,
                success: function(tab){
                    alert('success');
                },
                error: function (tab) {
                    alert('error');
                }
            });
    }
```

In the controller B:

```
public function viewresult()
{
echo 'SUCCESS';
}
```

The problem is that in the 'response' of ajax, I've 'SUCCESS' but also the entire view A, I don't understand why... 
I want only 'SUCCESS'...

Thanks in advance !

Comment: don't echo put return 'SUCCESS';exit(); and try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve it is adding `die()` at the end of your function so it prevents to load whole layout:

```
public function viewresult()
{
    echo 'SUCCESS';
    die;
}
```

OR

```
public function viewresult()
{
    die('SUCCESS');
}
```

---

But more conventional way is using [JSONView](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html). Your action should look as follows:

```
public function viewresult()
{
    $this->set('text', 'SUCCESS');
    $this->set('_serialize', ['text']);
}
```

You also have to load `RequestHandler` component in `initialize()` method in your controller:

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();

    $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
}
```

You need to set allowed extensions for all routes connected later in `routes.php`:

```
Router::extensions('json', 'xml');
```

Now you can access your action adding extension `.json` at the end of it's URL, so you need to modify ajax call url:

```
url:"<?php echo Router::url(array('controller'=>'Main','action'=>'viewresult', '_ext' => 'json'));?>"
```

That's all, but keep in mind that this solution force you to handle JSON array in response. In this example output will be looks as follows:

```
{"text": "SUCCESS"}
```

Answer (score 4):

Detect if its ajax as per following code in cakephp way :

```
    if($this->request->is('Ajax')) //Ajax Detection
    {
        $this->autoRender = false; // Set Render False
        $this->response->body('Success');
        return $this->response;
    }
```

Check here for more detectors - http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#Cake\Network\Request::addDetector

You can also use $this->Url->build instead of including Router for creating links in view.

```
echo $this->Url->build(['action'=>'index']);
```

Comment: or use the [Ajax](https://travis-ci.org/dereuromark/cakephp-ajax) plugin and cleanly return a json array to work with in the view. Then you dont need the is(ajax) check.

Comment: you saved my day. Works perfect